# What is the difference between a function prototype and a function implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm supposed to put my implementations in one file and my prototypes in a header file. But the way I understand it, a header file full of prototypes would not be very useful. What are these things? Is one of them identical to a definition or a declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function prototype is a function declaration that declares the types of its arguments.  This distinction is historical.  In C, it is possible to declare a function without a prototype, but in C++ all function declarations are prototypes (so there is no difference in C++).

```
// In C, this is a declaration but NOT a prototype.
// In C, this function takes an unknown number of parameters.
// In C++, this is a prototype, and the function has no arguments.
void f();

// In C, this is a prototype for a function with no arguments.
// In C++, it is the same thing.
void f(void);
```

In C++, you can't call functions unless you have a declaration/prototype for the function.  That is the use of header files.

(In C, you can call functions without a declaration, but this is considered a bad idea, and you only see it in *really* old code.)

Comment: So I need to write the code for my functions in the cpp file, and declare my functions in the header file?

Comment: @ZacharyF: You only need to declare functions that you want to call from other .cpp files.

Comment: _"In C++, you can't call functions unless you have a declaration/prototype for the function."_, that's untrue! A prototype is needed only when used in other compilation units (roughly, other .cpp files) or before being defined. Besides, this is true for C99 and C11 too.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: A definition is also a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

A function prototype is a declaration of a function: its name, parameters and return type. Unlike a full definition, the prototype terminates in a semi-colon.

```
int myfunc(double param) ;
```

The actual names of the parameter values (param in above example) can be left out of the prototype. This gives the flexibility of renaming variables at will.

Prototypes are used in header files so that external functions from other files can be called and the compiler can check the parameters during compilation.

A function prototype can be used to forward declare a function. A forward declaration is when a function or class is declared in advance of where it is implemented.