# What does "optional prototyping in C whereas mandatory prototyping in C++" mean?

Tags: c++, c

On [page 249](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=3fPEuyxmsW4C&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%22ANSI%20C%20borrowed%20prototyping%20from%20C%2B%2B,%20but%20the%20two%20languages%20do%20have%20some%20differences%22&source=bl&ots=_37v2o7l04&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ANSI%20C%20borrowed%20prototyping%20from%20C%2B%2B%2C%20but%20the%20two%20languages%20do%20have%20some%20differences%22&f=false), "C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata" says

> ANSI C borrowed prototyping from C++, but the two languages do have
> some differences. The most important is that ANSI C, to preserve
> compatibility with classic C, made prototyping optional, whereas C++
> makes prototyping mandatory. For example, consider the following
> function declaration

What "does optional in C whereas mandatory in C++" mean in terms of prototyping?

The only form I can imagine is like the following

```
#include <iostream>
void printHello(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello\n";
}
int main(){
    printHello();
}
```

Both C and C++ require defining functions before using them if no prototype provided in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printHello(){
    printf("Hello\n");
}
int main(){
    printHello();
}
```

Comment: Optional:  `void foo();`  Mandatory:  `void foo(int, int, char, char);`

Comment: It seems like you're confusing function declarations with prototypes

Comment: BTW , ANSI C didn't even require functions to be declared, if they returned `int` and had parameters limited to certain types

Comment: In C++, `void foo()` indicates that `foo` takes no arguments. In C, `void foo()` means that `foo` takes a fixed but unspecified number and type(s) of arguments. The C equivalent of C++'s ``void foo()` is `void foo(void)`. (C++ permits but does not encourage the `(void)` syntax for compatibility with C.)

Comment: @M.M I've been considering function declarations and prototypes the same thing in terms of C++. This post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390905) seems to support this understanding.

Comment: @PutBere They are different in C

Comment: @M.M Thank you. What's the difference between them in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C’s original style of function declarations and definitions did not specify the types of the arguments in the argument list. For example:

```
/**
 * Old style function declaration - the parameter list only
 * specifies the argument names. 
 */
int foo( x, y, z ); 

/**
 * Old-style function definition - the parameter list
 * only specifies the argument names, their types are
 * specified in separate declaration statements.
 */
int foo( x, y, z ) 
  int x;
  char *y;
  double z;
{
  /* function body */
}
```

An empty parameter list in a function definition meant the function took no arguments, whereas an empty parameter list in a function declaration meant the function took an unknown number of arguments.

One weakness with this style is that it didn’t give the compiler a good way to check if the parameters in a function call matched up with the function definition.  When he developed C++, Stroustrup introduced function prototype syntax, where the types of the parameters are specified in the argument list for both declarations and definitions:

```
/**
 * Declaration using prototype syntax
 */
int foo( int x, char *y, double z );

/**
 * Function definition using prototype syntax
 */
int foo( int x, char *y, double z )
{
  // function body
}
```

C adopted prototype syntax for C89, but still supports the old style syntax for backwards compatibility. C++ only ever used prototype syntax and never supported old-style C syntax.

Answer (score 3):

A function's [prototype](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-user-defined-functions#function-prototype) includes the number and types of its arguments. In C, one can declare a function without specifying these.

Consider the following program. It is permitted by C but not by C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo();

int main(){
  foo(1);
}

void foo(int c) {
  printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Note that in C++, the declaration of `foo()` means "it takes no arguments", whereas in C it means "indeterminate number of arguments of indeterminate types, but it isn't a variadic function (with `, ...` at the end of the argument list).